# The preview windows in the Blender VSE does not have sound and a blank screen

Tags: video, audio

First of all, I know this has been asked before, however, none of the answers from those post fixed my issue.  So I need this answered, so please respond and don't flag this.

When I preview my project in the Blender VSE, there is no sound or video.  The files are still where the path is.  What should I do.  I opened it a few times and it always does this.[image]

Comment: The file is sitting in the PC\Downloads folder alright but from here it looks like the VSE is looking for it in another folder.   When you can't see it in the preview window and you appear to have that activated, it's usually because the VSE can't see the file where it's looking.   Select the video strip, press N and goto the source folder icon and change the path and file to the PC\downloads\ etc, see how that goes.